# Vectorization of selective cumulative sum

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a `pandas Series` where each element is a list with indices:

```
series_example = pd.Series([[1, 3, 2], [1, 2]])
```

In addition, I have an array with values associated to every index:

```
arr_example = np.array([3., 0.5, 0.25, 0.1])
```

I want to create a new `Series` with the cumulative sums of the elements of the array given by the indices in the row of the input `Series`. In the example, the output `Series` would have the following contents:

```
0    [0.5, 0.6, 0.85]
1    [0.5, 0.75]
dtype: object
```

The non-vectorized way to do it would be the following:

```
def non_vector_transform(series, array):
    series_output = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(series_example)), dtype = object)
    for i in range(len(series)):
        element_list = series[i]
        series_output[i] = []   
        acum = 0
        for element in element_list:
            acum += array[element]
            series_output[i].append(acum)
    return series_output
```

I would like to do this in a vectorized way. Any vectorization magician to help me in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
series_example = pd.Series([[1, 3, 2], [1, 2]])
arr_example = np.array([3., 0.5, 0.25, 0.1])
result = series_example.apply(lambda x: np.cumsum(arr_example[x]))
print(result)
```

Or if you prefer a `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
series_example = pd.Series([[1, 3, 2], [1, 2]])
arr_example = np.array([3., 0.5, 0.25, 0.1])
# Copy only if you do not want to overwrite the original series
result = series_example.copy()
for i, x in result.iteritems():
    result[i] = np.cumsum(arr_example[x])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
0    [0.5, 0.6, 0.85]
1         [0.5, 0.75]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I see. The issue is that this vectorizes column-wise. I am wondering if it is possible vectorize row-wise as well.

Comment: @DavidMasip What rows and columns do you mean here? A `pd.Series` is just a single row/column... Do you have a `pd.DataFrame` instead?

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain properly. Here you are vectorizing the operation you perform in every row by using cumsum. However, apply does not fully vectorize, in the sense that it is better to do plain numpy operations than apply, as I have understood. In fact, some people claim that apply is even slower than loops: https://ys-l.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/how-not-to-use-pandas-apply/

Comment: at least he vectorizes the `cumsum`. I don't know whether you can vectorize the operations on the list

Comment: Yes, I totally agree.

Comment: @DavidMasip I think I understand what you mean... The problem is that each list has different size, so I'm not sure how you could vectorize it better (which is not to say I'm 100% sure it can't be done). About performance, `apply` is generally somewhat better than a loop, but as the link you posted points out it can fall into bad cases. This is not the case described there (you have a `pd.Series`, not `pd.DataFrame` and `np.cumsum` returns `np.ndarray`, not `pd.Series`), but I can't tell whether it is particularly inefficient also here for some reason. I've added a loop solution too anyway.